# REST API Management to deploy the GIT source

Tags: github, deployment, azure-deployment, azure-management-api

I'm creating a Web Application using API Managements and wanted to deploy the source code from GIT to Azure Portal using API Managements.

Could anyone guide me on this?

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

API Management works as proxy for your APIs - you won't be able to create a web application with it, but you can connect to a REST service running in a web application. Can you explain a bit more about your scenario and what you want to achieve?

Many thanks

Comment: I suspect this is a Azure Management API question.  I switched the tag around.